# Getting current selected value from state drop down list

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am trying to write a Java based Selenium test and having difficulties obtaining the selected value of a drop down.  Currently I have the following:

Page Helper:

```
protected String getTextFromCurrentSelection(By element) {
return new
Select(findWebElementBy(element)).getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
}
```

My code:

```
 public String getResidentStateDropDownText() {
    getTextFromCurrentSelection(residentStateDropDown);
    return waitAndGetText(residentStateDropDown);
    }
```

Assert:

```
assertEquals("CA - California", 
nonResidentRenewalPage.getResidentStateDropDownText());
```

My problem is that the entire drop down is returned instead of the value selected.  The selected value should be CA - California.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is `getTextFromCurrentSelection()` all about?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change this to

```
public String getResidentStateDropDownText() {
    return getTextFromCurrentSelection(residentStateDropDown);
}
```

You were returning the element and not doing anything with the return from `getTextFromCurrentSelection()`.